# What is the difference between URL refer ad click in google adwords?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am using **google-adwords** for text advertising in google and I want to know when Google use this referral

```
https://www.google.com/aclk
```

or this

```
https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=
```

as ad-click referer?

And is there any way to change "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=" to "https://www.google.com/aclk"?

Comment: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2015/09/referrer-changes-for-ad-clicks.html

Comment: i know about this post but in the post not any answer for my question ...